# Remove dynamic objects from array once they're removed from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the fiddle I created a button that adds a new object to both the document and an array.
Clicking on each object removes it from the document. How can I also remove it from the array?

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ghostClinic/aXt69/4/).

```
<button id="btn">addBox</button>
<p style="font-size: 12px">click boxes to remove</p>
<p id="p2" style="font-size: 12px"></p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        boxes = []
        boxNumber = 0
        function Box() {
            this.output = $("<div />").addClass('box').attr('id', "box" + boxNumber++).appendTo("body");
            boxes.push(this);
        }

        function addBox() {
            var box = new Box();
            $('.box').each(function() {
                var boxID = $(this).attr('id');
                $(this).text(boxID);
            });
            $('#p2').text(boxes);
        }

        function removeBox() {
            $(this).remove();
        }

        $('body').on('click', '.box', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        $('#btn').click(addBox);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Look at: [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Find the DOM element in the array, use .splice() to remove an item from the array.  But, one might ask why you even have the array, when you can generate the array at any time with a query of the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

To remove an element from the array, you find it and then use `.splice()` to remove it:

```
$('body').on('click', '.box', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (boxes[i].output[0] === this) {
            boxes.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hMcyd/

---

I'd suggest that you probably don't need to keep the boxes array in the first place as you can just generate an array of DOM elements upon demand at any time with this in a jQuery object:

```
var boxes = $(".boxes");
```

or, if you really want them in an array of DOM elements:

```
var boxes = $(".boxes").toArray();
```

---

It is common these days to NOT maintain a parallel array of elements in javascript that you can just dynamically retrieve at any time from the DOM whenever you need them.  CPUs are plenty fast these days that a user triggered operation will be plenty fast, even if it starts by building a list of objects with a DOM query.

Comment: so can you just post a correct fiddle that would be helpful

Comment: @susheel - it appears that your code is an array of BOX objects, not an array of DOM elements (your code is not very clearly written).  I will update my answer.

Comment: Thats not my code by the way..just trying to make the answer better.

Comment: Code updated to deal with the fact that the array is an array of Box objects.

Comment: @susheel - jsFiddle added.  It seems pointless that the OP is double maintaining this array of Box objects.

Answer (score 1):

as @jfriend00 mentioned, would be easier to just create a new array...

```
$('body').on('click', '.box', function() {
  $(this).remove();
  boxes = $('.box');
});
```

here is a fiddle to demonstrate.. http://jsfiddle.net/qs55y/

Comment: `boxes` in the OP's code is NOT an array of DOM objects or a jQuery object.  It's an array of `Box` objects that each has a DOM object in it.  As such, your suggestion is not doing the same thing the OP's code does.

Comment: @jfriend00 - noted - yeah missed the fact he was creating instances of a 'Box' .. your answer is more exact/correct

Comment: @jsuna - yeah, I missed that originally too.  The OP's code is not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of things, the easiest is to do a linear search on the array, then make a new array. This is not the most efficient way to do it. Might I add, you should rethink creating the Box object.

```
$('body').on('click', '.box', function() {
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      if(boxes[i].output[0] === this) break;
      tmp.push(boxes[i]);
    }
    boxes = tmp;
    $(this).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gSH4T/2/

Answer (score 0):

Search the array for the id attribute of the clicked box, and splice the boxes array with that index.

```
$('body').on('click', '.box', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.remove();
    $.each(boxes, function(index, value){
        if (this.output.attr('id') === self.attr('id')){
            boxes.splice(index, 1);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, you can update your list of objects in the view by calling `$('#p2').text(boxes);` after the each loop... though I'm not sure why you would want to list those out in the first place.